# Keep getting high-hash error from bitcoind

Tags: solo-mining, getblocktemplate

I'm sending this json to bitcoind server running in regtest mode:

```json
{"jsonrpc": 2.0,
 "id": "cumainer",
 "method": "submitblock",
 "params": ["000000200f9188f13cb7b2c71f2a335e3a4fc328bf5beb436012afca590b1a11466e2206a2db7dd515bcb1592ad65c2d5963e217120876d742f7b10d77d1a481017f4fb1ffff7f20a228fa6462a200000101000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ffffffff00000000010000000000000001000000000000000000000000a228fa64"] 
}
```

First 80 bytes are my block header, 1 meaning the number of transactions and my coinbase transaction in raw hex.

My regtest server is fresh and it has only one block.

For some reason I always get "high-hash" result from the server.
However if I take first 80 bytes (block header size) of my "params" string and double hash it I get a string with few zeros at the beggining. `getblocktemplate` request gives me the first difficulty (0x207fffff = the easiest one) and I'm sending it back in little endian order as stated on `submitblock` reference (I actually tried sending in big-endian too).

So the double sha256 hash of my block header is clearly smaller than the target.
What does this error mean then ? What I am doing wrong ? Is it the byte order? Maybe the problem is actually with the merkle root hash ?

Answer (score 2):

I tried to make sense of the data you submitted:

000000200f9188f13cb7b2c71f2a335e3a4fc328bf5beb436012afca590b1a11466e2206a2db7dd515bcb1592ad65c2d5963e217120876d742f7b10d77d1a481017f4fb1ffff7f20a228fa6462a200000101000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ffffffff00000000010000000000000001000000000000000000000000a228fa64

Here's how far I got before giving up

| Hex | Should be | Concerns |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `00000020` | block version? | ***Digit* order looks reversed!** |
| `0f9188f13cb7b2c7` `1f2a335e3a4fc328` `bf5beb436012afca` `590b1a11466e2206` | ID of prior block |  |
| `a2db7dd515bcb159` `2ad65c2d5963e217` `120876d742f7b10d` `77d1a481017f4fb1` | merkle root |  |
| `ffff7f20` | timestamp | **This looks wrong! Looks like target bits in wrong place** |
| `a228fa64` | target bits | **Probably misplaced timestamp or nonce?** |
| `62a20000` | nonce | **Could be a valid timestamp in wrong place?** |
| `01` | block contains 1 transaction |  |
| `01000000` | tx version |  |
| `01` | tx has one input |  |
| `0000000000000000` `0000000000000000` `0000000000000000` `0000000000000000` | referenced txid (all 0 for coinbase input) |  |
| `ffffffff` | vout index (for coinbase input) |  |
| `00` | length of unlocking script | **What about BIP34?** |
| `00000001` | sequence? | **Normally `ffffffff`** |
| `00` | number of outputs | **Can't be zero!** |
| `00000000` | Locktime |  |
| `00` `00` `01` `00` `00` `00` `00` `00` `00` `00` `00` `00` `00` `00` `00` |  | **Surplus data?** |
| `a228fa64` |  | **Repeat of data in target bits! So potentially intended as a locktime?** |

Maybe I am mistaken but that data doesn't look right to me

I recommend reading

- https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/block_chain.html#block-headers
- [Some doubts regarding the structure of the Coinbase Transaction?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/108187/13866)

Comment: The vout index for a coinbase input actually has to be 0xffffffff.

Comment: @Pieter thanks for pointing that out, answer corrected accordingly